# REDUX - spread operator returning different result in comparison with concat method

Tags: redux

I'm trying to learn what is the correct way to operate with Redux. I see around a lot of examples using the spread operator but I'm getting confused how to use it.

For instance, in the code below I have a very simple example where I fire in sequence the same action twice to simulate some products added to the cart.
the first action adds an array with two products while the second adds one product.
If I use concat to save the product in the state, I get the expected result of a cart array of three products:

```
    "use strict"
    import {createStore} from 'redux';

    // REDUCERS
    const reducer = function(state={cart:[]}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_CART":

        //HERE I ADD MY NEW ARRAY TO THE EXISTING ARRAY IN TEH STATE
        let cart = [...state.cart].concat(action.payload);
         return   {...state, cart}

          break;

      }
      return state
    }

    // CREATE STORE
    const store = createStore(reducer);

    // SUBSCRIBE
    store.subscribe(function() {
      console.log("current state is", store.getState());

    })

    // ACTIONS
    store.dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_CART",
      payload:[ {
        productId: 1,
        name: "Product A",
        price: 33.33
      },
      {
        productId: 2,
        name: "Product B",
        price: 15.00
      }]
    })

    store.dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_CART",
      payload:
      [{
        productId: 3,
        name: "Product C",
        price: 40.00
      }]
    })
```

Here is the result as I expected:

[image]

If instead I use the spread operator as below, I get a strange result where Redux creates two object, one containing two array with the product added from the first fired action and one object containing the third array/products:

"use strict"
        import {createStore} from 'redux';

```
    // REDUCERS
    const reducer = function(state={cart:[]}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_CART":

        //HERE I ADD MY NEW ARRAY TO THE EXISTING ARRAY IN TEH STATE
        return   {...state, cart:[...state.cart, action.payload]}

          break;

      }
      return state
    }

    // CREATE STORE
    const store = createStore(reducer);

    // SUBSCRIBE
    store.subscribe(function() {
      console.log("current state is", store.getState());

    })

    // ACTIONS
    store.dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_CART",
      payload:[ {
        productId: 1,
        name: "Product A",
        price: 33.33
      },
      {
        productId: 2,
        name: "Product B",
        price: 15.00
      }]
    })

    store.dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_CART",
      payload:
      [{
        productId: 3,
        name: "Product C",
        price: 40.00
      }]
    })
```

and this is the result from Chrome console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The spread example doesn't work because the payload is an array:

```
  payload:[ {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Product A",
    price: 33.33
  },
  {
    productId: 2,
    name: "Product B",
    price: 15.00
  }]
})
```

The solution is to spread the payload as well:

```
state = {...state, cart: [...state.cart, ...action.payload] };
```

---

Example:

```js
let state = { cart: [{ id: 1 }] };

const action = { payload: [{ id: 2}, { id: 3}] };



state = {...state, cart: [...state.cart, ...action.payload] };
         
console.log(state);
```

---

Note: since `state.cart` is an array, if you use `Array#concat`, you can simplify this:

```
[...state.cart].concat(action.payload);
```

By removing the spread and the wrapping array:

```
state.cart.concat(action.payload);
```